# Is there name for points where function abruptly changes its behaviour?

Tags: terminology

For example $f(x) = 1_{\{x < 0\}}x + 1_{\{x > 0\}}x^2$. Before and after $x = 0$ there are two different functions. Is there any name for such points?

I am aware of critical points, extremum points, stationary points, inflection points

Comment: I doubt it's relevant in this context, but perhaps "bifurcation point"? In ODEs that's used to indicate when the solutions to ODEs/stability of ODEs to change their behaviour

Comment: @peek-a-boo Actually I think its good, I can accept this as an answer

Comment: It is a point of non-differentiability, but I feel this is not what you are getting at. I think you are talking about the fact that you have a piecewise defined function which is given by a different formula at both ends of that point. But this is hard to pin down because what is and what is not allowed as a formula?

Comment: It is not a bifurcarion point, as @peek-a-boo also points out himself, so that should not be put as an anwer. It is just an interesting comment.

Comment: @JensRenders: piecewise must be qualified. This gives an opportunity to specify what is allowed. E.g. piecewise cologarithmic. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is $C^0$ (continuous) but not $C^1$ (the derivative at $x=0^-$ is different from the derivative at $x=0^+$: as @Jens Renders pointed out it is just a point of non-differentiability (see the first example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness)).

In the language of phase transitions (according to the classification by Ehrenfest) you may say that at $x=1$ there is a first order phase transition (if you interpret your $f$ as a thermodynamic potential, like the free energy).

Comment: Don't you mean $x=0$ ?

Comment: yes, sorry! a stupid lapsus,  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to express that the function has a different analytical expression in different parts of its domain, you should call it *piecewise*.

In the given example, it would be piecewise quadratic (accepting that the linear part is a "degenerate" quadratic).

---

Also note that your function has an *angular point* at the origin.